# How to run single test in new tab from WebStorm test explorer?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, webstorm, test-explorer

I executed "All Tests" in WebStorm and all my Jest tests are shown in the test explorer.

Now I would like to run some of the failed tests (e.g. treezColorArea.test.js) in a new tab. After fixing that test I would like to go back to the current tab and go on with the next failed test.

However, if I right click on a test and select "Run ...", the current tab "All Tests" is lost and only the single test is shown. In order to show all tests again, I have to rerun all tests.

**Question:** How can I run a single test in a new tab and keep the current (main) tab?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `Pin` icon? Just once, before doing your "right click and run that specific test"?

Comment: Perfect. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Pin** icon to pin these results. New test runs will now be opened in a separate tool window tab next to this one.

[image]